# Understand this Residue

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

> To determine that residue, we recall (Sec. 64) the Maclaurin series representation
>   $$
> e^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}\quad(|z|\lt\infty)
> $$
>   and use it to write
>   $$
> \frac{e^z-1}{z^5}=\frac1{z^5}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^{n-5}}{n!}\quad(0\lt|z|\lt\infty).
> $$
>   The coefficient of $1/z$ in this last series occurs when $n-5=-1$, or when $n=4$. Hence
>   $$
> \operatorname*{Res}_{z=0}\frac{e^z-1}{z^5}=\frac1{4!}=\frac1{24};
> $$
>   and so
>   $$
> \int_C\frac{e^x-1}{z^4}\,\mathrm{d}z=2\pi i\left(\frac1{24}\right)=\frac{\pi i}{12}.
> $$

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maN6W.jpg)

So I am reading this section on residues but I don't seem to quite understand why the Maclaurin series was evaluated for $\frac{e^z-1}{z^5}$ instead of $\frac{e^z-1}{z^4}$.

Remark: This is taken from "Complex Variables and Applications" - James Ward Brown and Ruel V. Churchill.

Comment: It seems a typo to me.

Comment: @SangchulLee I feel as if though this is the case but now I'm unsure of the actual result.

Comment: @ElSpiffy: I have added a latex equivalent of your image. It is sometimes better for readability and definitely better for searchability (and to a decreasing extent, better for the bandwidth used to load the page). It might be good if you would add a reference for what book that was taken from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly it is a typo. With the same method you can see that
$$
\mbox{Res}_{z=0} \left( \frac{e^z-1}{z^4}\right)=\frac{1}{6}
$$
so
$$
\int_C \frac{e^z-1}{z^4} dz= 2\pi i \cdot \frac{1}{6}
$$

Comment: Just to be sure, this book also does this method to solve this integral but instead of doing a Laurent series expansion for $cosh(1/z^2) $ it does it for $cosh(1/z)$, is this as well a typo? $$
 \int_C cosh(\frac{1}{z^2})= 0
 $$

Comment: It is better if you post another question and well illustrate the problem because the series expansion of $cosh (1/z^2)$ is not so simple.

Answer (score 1):

It is a typo. If we change the last equation to
$$
\int_C\frac{e^z-1}{z^\color{#C00}{5}}\,\mathrm{d}z=2\pi i\left(\frac1{24}\right)=\frac{\pi i}{12}
$$
everything else is good.